# My website is having some problems in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Hey all my website [www.heavylinker.com](http://www.heavylinker.com) works nice in Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome.
But when it comes to IE it all messes up...
I use CSS codes...

Any Ideas?

Comment: Look here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing a snippet of code it's impossible to diagnose the problem but in many cases with IE you can solve your problems by using a DOCTYPE declaration at the top of your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
...
```

Other than that you're probably using features IE doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an opening HTML tag.

```
<html>    <!--This is the tag you are missing -->
```

your IE conditional comment is also messed up. it should be:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

the **rel="stylesheet"** is what was missing/wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The first step towards browsers compatibility is to use the W3C free tools to analyze your code.

This is a report for your website:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.heavylinker.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

The CSS validator is a wonderful tool, too:

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

You might consider c-css.php (have a look at http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Conditional-CSS).

With that you're able to code for different browsers in one css file.
For me personally, a call it my best friend for css coding